# Django 1.7 URLs Mapping

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I'm getting a behavior that's really not making sense to me regarding the urls in my django project.  This isn't my first django project, so I'm sure it's something stupid, but I'm on day 2, and whatever it is, I can't find it.

I have a project **vote**.  In **vote/urls.py**:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^users/', include('users.urls')),
    url(r'^manage/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Within the project, I have an app **users**, I have the file **users/urls.py**:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns

from users import services

urlpatterns = patterns(
    url(r'^register/$', services.RegisterUser.as_view()),
)
```

Yet, when I runserver and navigate to localhost:8000/users/register/ I get a 404 error:

```
Using the URLconf defined in wevote.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^manage/
The current URL, users/register/, didn't match any of these.
```

For some reason, it's not pulling in the users.urls, and I can't figure out why.  I have both 'users' and 'rest_framework' in INSTALLED_APPS.  Any help would be appreciated.

Additional information:  From settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'rest_framework',
    'ujson',

    'analytics',
    'elections',
    'offices',
    'users'
)
```

Also, the project structure:

**vote**

- **analytics**
- **elections**
- **offices**
- **users**

  - urls.py
  - ...
- **vote**

  - settings.py
  - urls.py
  - ...
- manage.py
- requirements.txt

Comment: as is the arrangement of folders and files

Comment: First, please show the directory structure you have and `INSTALLED_APPS` setting. Also, well, it is silly, but does removing `pyc` files and restarting the server help? Thanks.

Comment: Removing the pyc files are restarting the server didn't help.  I also added the INSTALLED_APPS section as well as the folder/file structure.  Is it possible users is a reserved word?  I'm going to try the same thing in another app and see if I get the same behavior.

Comment: Not a reserved word issue.  I made a copy of the users/urls.py to analytics/urls.py.  Now when I navigate to localhost:8000/analytics/register/ it searches: ^users/ and ^manage/ and when I navigate to localhost:8000/users/register/ and it searches: ^analytics/ and ^manage/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are missing the prefix (the first positional argument) in your call to `patterns` in `users/urls.py`.  Try adding it:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns

from users import services

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^register/$', services.RegisterUser.as_view()),
)
```